# Can I customize my MUI Slider thumb to have bigger text?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, slider

I am using the MUI-Slider component in React to display a value. I would like to customize the 'thumb'/valueLabel so the font and thumb are much larger. I read MUI's documentation on updating the CSS to customize the thumb with limited success. [My slider looks like this currently](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NyRPu.png). The thumb and dot are blue, but everything else is grey. The font is still very small.

Here is my React component:
Note: the sx usage is copied [directly from the MUI documentation.](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/how-to-customize/)

```
import { Slider } from '@material-ui/core';

<Slider
      disabled
      min={0}
      max={100}
      value={50}
      marks={[
        { value: 0, label: '0' },
        { value: 100, label: '100' },
      ]}
      aria-label="Conviction Score"
      color="primary"
      sx={{
        '& .MuiSlider-thumb': {
          borderRadius: '1px',
        },
      }}
      valueLabelDisplay="on"
      orientation="vertical"
      valueLabelFormat={value => `${value.toFixed(1)}`}
    ></Slider>
```

I added this to my SCSS. Clearly I can change the thumb color but not any of the font attributes.

```
  color:#0d47a1;
  font-size: 20px !important;
  font-weight: bold !important;
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there any way I can do this with just CSS?

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your `sx` in the `Slider` component to replace the one you have now.

```
sx={{
    "& .MuiSlider-thumb": {
      borderRadius: "1px"
    },
    "& .MuiSlider-valueLabelLabel": {
      fontSize: "20px",
      fontWeight: "bold",
      color: "#0d47a1"
    }
  }}
```